# Alter $_ in execution command under perl script

Tags: regex, string, perl

In my code have a line as below,

```
my $status = `/usr/bin/ps -ef | grep $_ | grep -v grep | awk '{print\$2}'`;
```

Which $_ contained string as below,

> /home/production/agt/PtpAgent.sh

Can I alter the $_ output value to be 'PtpAgent' in the execution command, for example,

```
my $status = `/usr/bin/ps -ef | grep <some_regex_pattern>$_<some_regex_pattern> | grep -v grep | awk '{print\$2}'`;
```

Comment: Yes, of course. But what's the problem here, doesn't it work for you?

Comment: @yacc doesnt work for me, I try multiple regex pattern but still cannot get an output as 'PtpAgent' only

Comment: Provide some example that doesn't work.

Comment: @yacc $_ =~ m/\/(\w+)/ this is what i wrote from last try

Comment: This cannot work. `=~ m/.../` is the matching operator, it won't change `$_`. Use `s|.*/||` instead.

Comment: You should do: `open(my $ps_handle, 'ps -ef|');` and finish the job in perl instead of using grep and awk.

Answer (score 1):

You can, I suggest you use s/// which defaults to $_

```
s#.*/(.*?)\.sh$#$1#
```

You can also do

```
$_=~s#.*/(.*?)\.sh$#$1#;
```

or

```
$_="some text";
```

let me also suggest you keep the pipes to a minimum and just use perl for the filtering. It's much cleaner

```
my $status = qx(/usr/bin/ps -ef ) ;
$status=~s/.*\n.*?(grep.*?)\n.*/$1/m;  #adjust the capture group accordingly
```

However, this is merely personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

hoffmeister's approach of minimizing the pipes and working with PERL regex would be good as you would just need to split on "/" and get the last element to get the string which you need. And then you can easily pass it on through the next phases of pipe.